# How to pass data from a JAX-RS service to a Polymer custom component?

Tags: java, html, rest, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm researching building a simple web app using Polymer. I'd like to pass an numerical id to a custom component.  I can accomplish this using JSP by adding the id to a map and passing it in to a Viewable:

```
private Response buildUI(LinkedHashMap<String, String> map) {
     return Response.ok(new Viewable("/MyApp", map)).build();
 }
```

I would prefer not to introduce JSP to handle a single value though.

Is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

The HTML code-in-progress is:

```
// MyApp.html

<html>
<head>
  <title>iron-form demo</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

  <script src="../../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="custom-form-element.html">
  <link rel="import" href="custom-id-element.html">
</head>
<body unresolved>

  <custom-form-element>
    <template>
      <form is="iron-form" method="get" action="/" id="basic">
        <custom-id-element value="{id}"/>
        <paper-button raised onclick="_submit(event)">Submit</paper-button>
      </form>
      <script>
        function _submit(event) {
          Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.submit();
        }
        basic.addEventListener('iron-form-submit', function(event) {
          this.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(event.detail);
        });
      </script>
    </template>
  </custom-form-element>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution was simple using the Polymer component "[app-route](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-route)".  My app is REST-based, and the ID is a resource, so it was logical to place it in the URI path:

```
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:id"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}">
</app-route>
```

Now I can databind to the id where I need it:

```
<iron-label>
    route = {{routeData.id}}
</iron-label>
```